# Android create custom ImageView that animates onClick

Tags: android, onclick, imageview, android-animation

To create an animation for a view..
From developer.android.com:

```
ImageView spaceshipImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.spaceshipImage);
Animation hyperspaceJumpAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.hyperspace_jump);
spaceshipImage.startAnimation(hyperspaceJumpAnimation);
```

I wonder if i could extend the ImageView so every MyImageView that i create would have the animation when clicked.

I should also then set a different OnClickListener outside the MyImageView class for every of these MyImageView(s).

Is that possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this approach...

```
    public class MyImageView extends ImageView implements
            View.OnClickListener {

        private View.OnClickListener clickListener;

        public MyImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
            super(context, attrs, defStyle);
            setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        public MyImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
            setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        public MyImageView(Context context) {
            super(context);
            setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void setOnClickListener(OnClickListener l) {
            if (l == this) {
                super.setOnClickListener(l);
            } else {
                clickListener = l;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // start the Animation...
            // handle click event yourself and pass the event to supplied
            // listener also...
            if (clickListener != null) {
                clickListener.onClick(this);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
try to use these code:::--->      


  ImageView spaceshipImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.spaceshipImage);
    spaceshipImage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Animation hyperspaceJumpAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.hyperspace_jump);
                    spaceshipImage.startAnimation(hyperspaceJumpAnimation);
                }
            });
```

Comment: thanks but i'm asking if i can extend this ImageView to always have the animation onClick.

Comment: are you satisfy then upvate me.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can extend ImageView and implements OnClickListener at the same time:

```
public class MyImageView extends ImageView implements View.OnClickListener {
}
```

remember to call `setOnClickListener(this)`, since your class is responsible to manage view's click, in the constructor(s). When the onClick is called you call `startAnimantion(yourAnimation)`.

Comment: Can i set a second onClickListener outside this view later?